# Phonetically annotated speech corpus

Tags: phonetics, corpora, resource-request, accent, annotation

Are there any phonetically annotated corpora of accented English speech?

Preferably English spoken by native English speakers with a strong accents, such as speakers from a specific region in the UK (Scotland, Liverpool etc), Ireland, Jamaica, Australia etc.

There are some great resources for accented speech, but only a part of IDEA seems to be phonetically annotated.

Could anyone please recommend a corpus of accented English speech that has been phonetically annotated and temporally aligned?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try the [George Mason Speech Accent Archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/). It's all annotated in IPA and includes non-native speakers and native speakers from all sorts of backgrounds. It's not a corpus, however; everybody says the same paragraph, which contains a vast amount of variable phonology.

Comment: Please post this as an answer @jlawler ...

Comment: Thank you very much @jlawler! That is a valuable resource. I was hoping to find longer stretches of speech so there could be less repetition of content. If anyone would know any other phonetically annotated accented speech corpora that have recordings of maybe 10 min per accent that would be very helpful please.

Comment: There's also [MICASE](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/c/corpus/corpus?c=micase;page=simple), but that's not annotated in IPA, I don't think. And it's ordinary talk, not particularly accented, though there are plenty of accents.

Answer (score 2):

1. The [TIMIT Corpus](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/ldc93s1) has "time-aligned orthographic, phonetic and word transcriptions" of eight major dialects of American English.
2. The textbook *Phonetic Analysis of Speech Corpora* by Jonathan Harrington has a list of example databases listed at [this website](http://www.phonetik.uni-muenchen.de/forschung/publikationen/harrington/pasc/Harrington_pasc_databases.php).  One listed database that may be of use to your research is the [Australian National Database of Spoken Language (ANDOSL)](http://andosl.rsise.anu.edu.au/andosl/).

This is all from a quick Google search and not meant to be comprehensive.  Checking out the textbook I mentioned might lead you to more useful citations.